# Specifying just the tenantid and not https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid} to UserAgentApplication

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

Lets say I have a single tenant application in my Azure AD tenant e426c4ff-bbb4-4edb-96c8-4e0244ff8fd0. I can't log into it via https://login.microsoftonline.com/common, only https://login.microsoftonline.com/e426c4ff-bbb4-4edb-96c8-4e0244ff8fd0.

It seems kind of weird that I can't pass just `e426c4ff-bbb4-4edb-96c8-4e0244ff8fd0` to the MSAL.js class `UserAgentApplication` though. Why must I pass https://login.microsoftonline.com/e426c4ff-bbb4-4edb-96c8-4e0244ff8fd0 as the second construction parameter

```
this.app = new UserAgentApplication(
  this.applicationConfig.clientID,
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/e426c4ff-bbb4-4edb-96c8-4e0244ff8fd0,
  function () {console.log('UserAgentApplication login callback arguments: ', arguments); });
```

I know I'm being a little bit nit-picky, but this seems wrong to have to construct a url in its entirely, when thats knowledge the msal.js library should internally have based on just the tenantid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authority` field (what you're referring to) has a few other configurable options besides single/multi-tenancy.

For example, MSAL.js can be used with Azure AD B2C which allows a `policy` to configured.  In that case, you would need to configure other parts of the `authority` beside the `tenantID`.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/<your-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<your-sign-in-sign-up-policy>
```

Comment: That's a fair point, one I had not realized during my ASP.NET Core Azure Auth development. However, shouldn't there be a helper class to generate that URL. Should I open github issues to talk about that?

Comment: Yes! Please open an issue and link it here.  It makes sense to help construct the URL either in code or have it prominent in documentation. Thank you!

Comment: Looking over old questions and found this. I ended up constructing my own configuration class to make the URLs, after the project was switched to B2C.

Comment: @JustinDearing, very interesting. Would love to see your config class if it's open source.